# Remove forward slash when tabbing to see a list of directories

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

Is there a way to remove the trailing forward slashes in the tab-completion output of Zsh when I start writing a `cd` command and tab to see a list of directories?

E.g.

```
~ cd <tab>
Adlm/                       Desktop/
Applications/               Development/
```

I was wondering if there's any way to remove the slashes after the directory names, to show `Adlm` instead of `Adlm/`, etc.

Comment: Pressing TAB to yield a menu of completions _is_ autocompletion.  But the purported duplicate is clearly about making a different shell mimic a different aspect of the Z shell (i.e. what happens in the resultant command line when a directory completion is selected rather than how directories are displayed in the menu by menu completion).

Comment: @JigglyNaga I came across that solution before I posted this question. I've even tried them as I have misunderstood the question at first. It does not work.

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed that you included the `zsh` and `oh-my-zsg` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, it's:

```
set +o list_types
```

When using [`complist`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fcomplist-Module), you can also change its color to make it  less visible:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors tc=33 ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

to make it yellow (less visible on a terminal with white background), and use the GNU `ls` colors (assuming you've run `eval "$(dircolors)"`) for the rest.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into this simple question :)

Comment: @user1164937, see latest edit though which you may have missed as you accepted the answer shortly after I made it.

Comment: I already had that line of code to match the colors of my theme just a few hours ago. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

I tested that solution, specifically the bind command:

```
bind 'set mark-directories off'
```

Comment: `$ zsh`, `% bind 'set mark-directories off'`, `zsh: command not found: bind`. Should that work with plain zsh, or is there something else that is required?